# if $x+y+z=0$ then $(\zeta(x) +\zeta(y) + \zeta(z))^2= \wp(x) + \wp(y) +\wp(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, elliptic-functions

I found that if $x+y+z=0$, one can prove that $(\zeta(x) +\zeta(y) + \zeta(z))^2= \wp(x) + \wp(y) +\wp(z)$ using Liouville's theorem (here $\wp$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function)

How one can do this?

Comment: Please add some context and your attempts. The question is pretty standard in theory of elliptic functions (complex analytic approach) and usually textbooks give many examples of proving such identities using Liouville theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$L=w_1\Bbb{Z}+w_2\Bbb{Z}$.

$\wp_L$ is the unique $L$-periodic meromorphic function whose poles are double at $L$ and $\wp_L(z)=z^{-2}+O(z)$.

$\zeta_L'=-\wp_L$ and $\zeta_L(z)=z^{-1}+O(z)$. It is the unique meromorphic function whose poles are simple at $L$, $\zeta_L(z)=z^{-1}+O(z)$ and $\zeta_L(z+w_j)=\zeta_L(z)+c_j$.

$$f_{L,y}(z)=(\zeta_L(-z-y) +\zeta_L(y) + \zeta_L(z))^2$$ is meromorphic doubly periodic with double poles at $L$ and $L-y$ where $f_{L,y}(z)=z^{-2}+O(1),f_{L,y}(z-y)=z^{-2}+O(1)$, thus $$g_{L,y}(z)=f_{L,y}(z)-\wp_L(z)-\wp_L(y-z)$$ is entire and $L$-periodic, it is constant.

Since $\zeta_L'=-\wp_L'$ and $\wp_L$ is even then $\zeta_L(z)=z^{-1}+O(z^2)$ and $$g_{L,y}(z)= (\wp_L(y) z+z^{-1}+O(z^2))^2-z^{-2}-\wp_L(-y)+O(z)=\wp_L(y)+O(z)$$
and hence $$g_{L,y}(z)=\wp_L(y)$$